# Need to create a queue to run process for one person at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, arcgis

I lack the knowledge to even know where to start researching this topic (such as keywords to use) so I'm hoping somebody can help point me in the right direction.

I have an .NET MVC application. In this application, the user uploads a zip file with a data layer and that data layer is used as input in a python script the application calls. Due to the nature of the database cursors (it's an ArcGIS Enterprise geodatabase if anyone is familiar) only one person can run the python script at a time as the cursors make exclusive locks on the database (there is no way around this). In the extremely rare chance that two people are trying to use this web application at the same time, I need to put the people in a queue so the python script completes for the first person and then starts on the next person's dataset. Where do I get started with this, or what words can you give me to start formulating some search queries on this topic?

Comment: Static / Singleton with some lock/mutex would be one of the approaches to look into to limit the usability to single instances rather than the Queue approach. If you really need to Queue request and process them one at a time , you can combine this with SignalR. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are more technology specific solutions will come, but from my first view, you can use **priority queue** style processing.

It can be as simple as creating a table and enqueue (insert) new requests over there and process as it comes (dequeue). Or, use higher level framework like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

So, every time when new zip file comes,

- Upload in repository
- Insert new record in the queue
- Get first item from queue
- Process

If second person uploads new file, you will check queue table, there will be flag last item is getting processed, then you can let client know, script is queued and will be processed.

Obviously it will be worth to generate unique id of client, then you will not mix priorities and scripts, if there are multiple uploads at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the Queue class since there really is no priority order, just whoever uploads stuff first gets processed first. I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how multiple users get enqueued/dequeued from a single queue though. I could instantiate a Queue class in my application when someone uploads data, add their stuff to the queue, but if a second user comes along and uploads data, I think it'd just end up instantiating another, separate Queue class. Is that where the "queue table" you mention would come in?

Comment: You will need to look at how to implement Singleton, or you will need to create Queue storage somewhere in persistence storage in SQL server etc and consume it. If you are a stranger to those concepts, I would highly recommend take support from more senior developer, or invest time to learn these concepts before you dive in. Anyway, you are on halfway, and should not take too long time to grasp them.